# deSolve Installing package error

Tags: r, installation, package, linux-mint

I am installing deSolve package, in R, linux mint. The following error stops installing:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [deSolve.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘deSolve’

Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Thanks
Maryam

Comment: The BLAS library (or its headers) are missing. You have to install it using Linux Mint package manager. On my system (Debian linux), it is  packages libopenblas-base and libopenblas-dev

Comment: Thanks. solved with this installation:  sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is solved. Please allow me to add that the problem was an incomplete installation of R's dependencies, not an issue of deSolve. **blas** and **lapack** are numerical libraries that are used by many packages.

The complete installation of R under Linux Mint (a Ubuntu resp. Debian derivate) can be found here:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

or

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/